# Good GUI for creating only a nameserver on a VPS

Tags: hosting, vps, nameserver

I want to run my own nameserver for all my domain and client. Now I have a [very small OpenVZ VPS](http://bluemilecloud.com/hosting/openvz-vps-servers/) which can run debian or centos.

Now I am a windows user, so I am not that good with SSH and text files, I really prefer a GUI.

I am looking for a small application that has a GUI for only doing DNS and nameserver, and only the stuff that is needed.

I looked at solutions such as [virtualmin](http://www.virtualmin.com/) and [kloxo](http://lxcenter.org/) but they come packed with email solution, webservers, databases, and all sort of things I do not need.

I only want to create my nameservers, and add my domains and point them to the web hosting servers.

Note: I prefer a free package

Comment: You may want to rephrase the title of your question. It wasn't clear to me what you were asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a GUI interface on a box that small, your best option may be to install something like [webmin](http://www.webmin.com) and use the web-based interface to perform your management tasks.  Webmin has a DNS management module that will handle the BIND DNS server configuration for you.

Comment: Cool this works great, much lighter that virtualmin!

Answer (score 4):

By far the most popular free DNS package out there is [BIND](http://www.isc.org/software/bind) from the ISC. Since it uses flat files, which you want to avoid, you can take a look at all of the [free GUI tools for managing a BIND DNS server](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/bindweb.htm).